# python- browse a file and use it with another command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I would like to extract text from a user chosen pdf. I wrote the code and it works. But i would like to execute the command with a button on a user browsed file (instead of having E01.2.4.pdf i would like to select the file chosen by the user). How can i change my code to do that?

browse file:

```
def OpenFile ():
file1 = filedialog.askopenfile (mode ="r") 
label = Label(text=file1).pack()
```

extract text:

```
def ExtractText ():
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('E01.2.4.pdf', 'rb'))
i = 0
while i<read_pdf.getNumPages():
    pageinfo = read_pdf.getPage (i)
    print(pageinfo.extractText())
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Look for Django/Flask frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the principle [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

One concern is requesting the filename from a user.

```
def openFile():
    """requests filename from user"""
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(mode ="r") 
    # ... further file name processing
    return filename
```

The other concern is processing the requested file:

```
def ExtractText(filename):
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'))
    for page in range(pdfReader.numPages):
        page = pdfReader.getPage(page)
        print(page.extractText())
        # ...
```